# Selecting data from MySQL in random order

Tags: php, mysql, select, random

I want to extract each row from a table, but in random order. How can I do that? I tried using `rand()`, but I was not successful.

My database is named "permis54_permis-online-date" and my table is named: "intrebari".

Comment: What did you try? Give us your query and error.

Comment: I don't have the code right now cause I delete it, I want to try something new..I have mind open to suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ORDER BY RAND()` MySQL:

```
SELECT column FROM intrebari
    ORDER BY RAND()
```

Comment: argh ssergei you're to fast - anyway so the example comes under your answer ;) - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77d523/2/0 - up

Comment: Ok, I will try now and get back with feedback

Comment: I succeed. Thank your very much. But now I want to extract only one row with his data fields. This can be done?

Comment: add ``LIMIT 1`` at the end of your query

Comment: Great. It works this too. Now look, the tabel "intrebari" contains fields like "intrebare", "A", "B", etc and I want to extract the value of all fields togheter with the question.

Comment: Basically, I want to extract with the question and the rest of the row field values​​.

Comment: I succed that too. That's all for today, thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from intrebari order by rand();
```